# Mongoose sorting from nearest to farthest

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Given a schema

```
{location: [Number]}
```

I need to sort from nearest.

```
MODEL.find({ location: 
    {'$near':
{'$geometry':
{type: 'Point',coordinates: currentlocation}},
    '$minDistance': 1,
    '$maxDistance': 10000000000000000000000,

  }).then(..).catch(..)
```

When I do so, I just get not found 404 error.

I am trying to get the list from nearest to farthest relative to the location.

Comment: You get a 404 from MongoDB?

Comment: I think I get 404 from postman.